# How to detect and cut out face using the Kinect (or something else)?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, kinect, face-recognition

I need to detect a face, and take that picture (only the face) and do something with that.

Just like you can "cut out" an entire body using the Kinect, I'd like to do the same but only with the face of the user.

I was using the Airkincet ANE lately, but I've read that any kind of face recognition/detection is not possible, so, I've also read that the MS Kinect SDK has some built in features that can recognize a face, the thing is, can I cut out the face?, or it only "recognizes"?.

Thanks, and sorry if the question is a little vague.

(It doesn't has to be a kinect, I can use a picture, and run an algorithm to cut out the face, since what I need is not real time).

Comment: Try something like this [face recognition library](https://code.google.com/p/face-recognition-library-as3/). From there it's just a matter of filling the result with black or whatever you want.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't "cut out" the face, it only draws a square where the face is.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the SDK's C# sample "Face Tracking-3D WPF". It uses facial tracking to extract your face from the Kinect's view and blow it up. If you have a Kinect you can run the sample and install it and modify. Hope this helps.

cheers